# EF ObjectContext returns always "Closed" connection state

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework

I need to know when the database connection (via WCF RIA + EF) is opened, when is closed. But in my DomainService (at web side) method:

```
return this.ObjectContext.Connection.State.ToString();
```

**Always** returns "closed". Even if just now was successful response. The connection really is opened after first request and automatically closes after time-out (configured in web.config) because in WFC RIA I do not invoke "open-" and "close connection" commands. But the main problem - it is if the connection time-outed, the DomainContext doesn't tell client side nothing about this.

So, if the connection time-outed and a user trying to make a request to database - he will get an exception (actually **access** exception), then, DomainContext **hidely** automatically restore the connection, and user can get an answer after second request (all after time-out).

That's why I need to know - when connection state is closed, when opened.

And I just want to make an indicator which can show the real connection state in a real-time.

And the second, less important question - Do I need to make one static DomainContext object to implicit any database actions (includes Login, Logout, GetQuerriess and et.c.)? Is it ok? getting new instances of DomainContext almost for each group of operations? Hope, you understood my thoughts.

Comment: [ HELD ]

http://forums.asp.net/t/1389167.aspx/1
Quote:
ConnectionTimeout specifies how long, in seconds, should the code wait before timing out from trying to OPEN a connection. It relates directly to the line connection.Open();
CommandTimeout specified how long, in seconds, should the command wait before timing out. This relates to calls such as Fill(),

Comment: Also, the Entity Framework without any special actions invokes Open and Close database commands. My problem looks like in Hosting of Database Settings.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Give us which exception exactly occurs. Which db are you using? How did you set connection-string? As I guessed you use entity framework,please summarize your question. Just tell us what is the error and what you want to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ado.NET you can manage connection's we say "connection pooling"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

EntityFramework also uses ADO.NET but an IIS server manages , optimized connection pooling for us.

I had never faced off such an connection closed error for years. If you give us more details maybe it will be clear. Generally after 20 second the web session get dead. Can it be a lost session?

We use DomainService classes for RIA services.(as I see in your question you wrote RIA)
DomainService class has ObjectContext's of it's EntityModel(EDMX). So you can reach them in your domain service methods by **this.ObjectContext**. If you have one EDMX you won't be need another instance of your ObjectContext. You may just need different instance of Domain Service Classes.

Comment: Thank you. The solution is in first and second comments of main post.